# Freeform Post Forwarding

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I need to catch the POST of a new user's submission where some fields need to be put on a child table.
I can't get the right hook to do it.
I created a module to catch the route and I put a debug info in it but there is no call whatsoever to the module/route.
Using the 3.12+ version of freeform, I see I can use

```
    url: "https://somesite.com/stuff",
    triggerPhrase: "success"
}
```

or even this feature in the form itself but looking at the Network console, no call is made.

[image]

Comment: You won't see anything in browser tools for POST Forwarding because the request is made server-side, not client-side (i.e., the server receives the form submission and then forwards it on to the URL specified). Additionally, the error trigger should be a trigger word for an unsuccessful response from the endpoint (which should originate from that endpoint).

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. I will try to go from there. Thanks !